# Get subprocess id in Java

Tags: java, linux, process

I'm creating subprocesses in this way:

```
String command = new String("some_program");

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

How I can get that subprocess id?

P.S. I'm working on Linux.

Comment: String commend = "some_program" is better in this case

Comment: It is not the real code. Just a snippet to describe the problem.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is still no public API for this (see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4244896) but there are workarounds.

A first workaround would be to use an external program like `ps` and to call it using `Runtime.exec()` to get the pid :)

Another one is based on the fact that the `java.lang.Process` class is abstract and that you actually get a concrete subclass depending on your platform. On Linux, you'll get a `java.lang.UnixProcess` which has a private field `int pid`. Using reflection, you can easily get the value of this field:

```
Field f = p.getClass().getDeclaredField("pid");
f.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println( f.get( p ) );
```

Comment: Good question! And I wonder why such a bug is open for 10+ years without resolution?

Comment: Probably because Sun want you to stay inside the JVM.

Comment: Maybe because the request is about java.lang.System. And putting PID there turns it into platform-specific, which is wrong. But UnixProcess has no reason for hiding it.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Just filled RFE @ sun.com to solve this problem.

Comment: @Bozho Well, you shouldn't actually have to manipulate a platform specific class like `UnixProcess`.

Comment: @Pawka - why don't you vote for the existing issue.  And get all your friends to as well.

Comment: Well, you don't manipulate it, you just get its state. If it is not part of the API, they should put it in com.sun.*

Answer (score 1):

I tried (and failed) to do this a while back. I ended up wrapping my command in a shell script that dumped the pid to a file. Not the best solution but it got me past this hurdle.

Comment: This was the 1st idea, what I thought. But it doesn't fits to me. The "command" could be almost any program, not prepared by my. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no documented way to do this, but it happens that the Process implementation class is UNIXProcess, and it has a pid field.  So you could use reflection to access this private field to get the ID.  Googling around you will find other tricks of calling another shell to get ps output and that kind of thing.  Nothing easy.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://blog.igorminar.com/2007/03/how-java-application-can-discover-its.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] bo = new byte[100];
    String[] cmd = {"bash", "-c", "echo $PPID"};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    p.getInputStream().read(bo);
    System.out.println(new String(bo));
}
```

Comment: I've found that post before, but it doesn't fits to me. I can't prepare of modify subprocess program that it would output PID.

Answer (score 0):

Given there is no public API to get the `pid` till now,

We can also apply the following trick obtain the `pid`:
IN CASE, YOU USE THE **[Liberica JDK](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-11-lts)**, if not, you can check if you can use the same idea or not:

```
String pid = process.toString().substring(12, process.toString().indexOf(','));
```

The idea behind the above code, after checking the `toString()` impl inside `ProcessImpl` class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder("Process[pid=").append(pid)
            .append(", exitValue=").append(hasExited ? exitcode : "\"not exited\"")
            .append("]").toString();
}
```

Cons:

- This  way depend on impl!
- When you change your JDK, you may change the parser to fetch the pid

Answer (score 0):

Using `Java 9`, now you can fetch the pid directly as it is defined in the Process API interface.

```
process.pid();
```

The main code of the Process interface

```
/**
 * Returns the native process ID of the process.
 * The native process ID is an identification number that the operating
 * system assigns to the process.
 *
 * @implSpec
 * The implementation of this method returns the process id as:
 * {@link #toHandle toHandle().pid()}.
 *
 * @return the native process id of the process
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the Process implementation
 *         does not support this operation
 * @since 9
 */
public long pid() {
    return toHandle().pid();
}
```