# Why is the Java type `UNIXProcess` not visible on my system?

Tags: java, unix

I am building a Java application that I intend to be used only on a Unix OS.

In the application I create some child processes using `ProcessBuilder` and want to interact with them in a native manner. So instead of using the interface provided by `Process` I would like to cast them to `UNIXProcess` after starting the child.

However I get this error when trying to use the Type.

```
import java.lang.UNIXProcess;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args) throws Exception
    {
        ProcessBuilder bp = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/echo", "hello");
        Process process = bp.start();
        UNIXProcess unixProcess = (UNIXProcess) process;

    }
}
```

> The type java.lang.UNIXProcess is not visible

Am I not supposed to be using UNIX Process?

I am seeing this error in Eclipse for Java 1.7, if that matters.

Comment: I don't think `UNIXProcess` is part of the API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UNIXProcess` is not declared `public`:

```
final class UNIXProcess extends Process
```

This means that it is only visible from within the `java.lang` package. Java prohibits you from using it outside of that package.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/UNIXProcess.java#36

Comment: Is there an alternative to `UNIXProcess` then? I'm trying to get access to `getPid()` among other things

Comment: @Mike A google search for "java unix get pid" lead me to this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897655/get-subprocess-id-in-java